# either file permission or password?

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, blocking, hosts-file

I want to block some sites permanently without any 3rd party app. So far internet is not helpful in this, all available solutions can be undone easily.

Is there any way I can add password to hosts file (will hit keyboard with closed eyes for password) so that it can't be opened.

Or

Can I change its file permissions in such a way that I will never be able to edit hosts file. The only solution will be to re-install OS.

PS: I'm a mac user. This is the [list of sites](http://pastebin.com/mr36CWPC) I want to block.

Bonus will be to block such content available through google searches for sites not included in this list.

Will really appreciate the effort.

Comment: The linked list has been removed from Pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

*Almost anything* that one can do through software can be undone.However, if you wish to make it annoyingly complex to undo, though, try this:

1. [Change the ownership of *hosts* to TrustedInstaller](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/irenak/2007/01/30/sysk-277-how-to-bring-back-the-trustedinstaller/)

   - Right mouse-button click on the file and choose Properties
   - Click Security tab
   - Click Advanced button
   - Click Owner tab
   - Click Edit button
   - Click Other User or Group and type in NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller
   - Remove permissions from users to write or delete the file
2. Use software to lock the file.

   - [System-Protect](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Security/Security-Related/System-Protect-Crawler.shtml) claims to lock files you select. However, I've not tried it, and one review states it's not effective.
   - You could lock the file by opening it in some application, e.g. MS Notepad or WordPad, at startup. You could even write a minuscule console application that just calls [File.Open Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx) in [FileShare Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx) mode. Just place it in a Startup folder, or if you're a bit craftier, make a Windows Service.

Given enough effort, this *could* be undone, but it would at least be an effective reminder not to visit those sites.

Comment: Thank You @DrMoishe, this will be helpful to a windows user. however I'm asking about  a user on the mac. I got this list from internet only. Can it be modified to block certain google links like `https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=xyz` before changing permissions or locking it.

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: At-least you came up with a feasible solution, even if its not workable for me. I really appreciate that, I'll try to work on it in my free time. Thank You DrMoishe.